# C++ variadic template deduction fail

Tags: c++, templates

I have written a variadic template function with recursive evaluation. For the final parameter I implemented a specialization without the variadic pack and everything worked fine.

Now I want to convert the variadic function parameters into template parameters.

This is my try:

```
template<typename N, int p> // specialization
N constexpr myadd(const N &n)
{
    return n + p;
}

template<typename N, int p, int ... v> // variadic
N constexpr myadd(const N &n)
{
    return myadd<N, v...>(n) + p;
}

int testfun()
{
    return myadd<int, 2>(7);
}
```

gcc and clang are reporting an **ambiguous overload** and can not decide between 'specialization' and 'variadic' **with an empty parameter pack**.

I tried removing the specialization and check for the pack size in the variadic template, but **without the specialization** the compilers are **failing to deduce parameter 'p'**.

Comment: Notice that there are no specializations, just different overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64985212/8769985), the variadic pack can be indeed empty.
But you can specialize the case of a non-empty variadic pack with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename N, int p> // specialization
N constexpr myadd(const N &n)
{
    std::cout << "specialization" << std::endl;
    return n + p;
}

template<typename N, int p, int ... v, class = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(v) > 0)>> // variadic
N constexpr myadd(const N &n)
{
    std::cout << "variadic" << std::endl;
    return myadd<N, v...>(n) + p;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout <<  myadd<int, 2>(7) << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  myadd<int, 2, 4>(7) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

See it [Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bebe2454e4638091).

Comment: or `template<typename N, int p1, int p2, int ... v> N constexpr myadd(const N&);` without SFINAE.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter pack can indeed be empty. You can avoid the ambiguity by changing the specialization to handle the case of not adding anything:

```
template<typename N> // specialization
N constexpr myadd(const N &n)
{
    return n;
}

template<typename N, N p, N ... v> // variadic
N constexpr myadd(const N &n)
{
    return myadd<N, v...>(n) + p;
}
```

With C++17, you can simplify this by using [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template<typename N, N ... v> // variadic
N constexpr myadd(const N &n)
{
    return (v + ... + n);
}
```

Comment: Good suggestions, but for the real algorithm there is no simple way to change it to fit your code. I went with @francesco 's solution.

Comment: What is different in your real algorithm?

Comment: You find the my original algorithm here: https://pastebin.com/7cUnGfnJ . I want to calc the least integer above 'n' with only given factors (to determine ideal FFT size).

Comment: But that algorithm passes the values as function parameters, not as template parameters, and will compile fine. I can see how a fold expression would not be appropriate there though.

Comment: You typically need a set of a few fixed, small integers which are known at compile time. With template parameters the compiler will craft a optimized instance. With parameters you could only get all optimizations for the parameters if the compiler inlines the code.

Comment: @m2j There is no guarantee that the compiler will optimize your code just because the values are passed as template parameters. The only reason you can get a compile-time result is because the compiler can inline things when the function body is present (whether or not it is a `template`). Even `constexpr` doesn't force the compiler to generate the result at compile time, it is just there to enforce you as the programmer to write the code in such a way thet the compiler *can* evaluate it at compile-time.

Comment: @g-sliepen You are right: the compiler will decide what to optimize. You may get the same binary with both versions. Still (AFAIK) for the template parameter variant the compiler will generate one instantiation with all parameters inlined. After that optimizations are done. The parameter variant can only inline the parameters in a optimization step and this will result in inlined code (I guess the compiler will not be able to share such code). I've used `constexpr` keyword here to enable static assertion tests.

Comment: @m2j There is no reason to assume the template parameter variant will generate one function with everything inlined. The only thing that is inlined is the value of the parameters. To illustrate, see this [assembly code generated by myadd()](https://godbolt.org/z/KGv7GW) without compiler optimizations turned on.

Comment: @g-sliepen: that is exactly what I meant. The parameters are inlined. Compare it to the [template with function parameters](https://godbolt.org/z/PfGWc3). I'm using divisions and thus it is a huge advantage if the compiler considers the fixed values.

Comment: @g-sliepen: I droped my code into Quick-Bench. At -O3 the generated code is different, but the performance is same. Going down to -O2 and below in gcc results in factor 2 in performance difference. So the behaviour is as expected, but in reality it is not relevant. At least I learned something.

Comment: @m2j Ah yes if divisions and modulo operations are involved I can see that even just inlining the constant will make a big difference!